# matplotlib layout like plotly by hand

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stylesheet

I am plotting with matplotlib and trying to get a nice layout like plotly. Especially I would like to have a bar chart/box plot with filling and contour in the same colour. Not as default black/grey contour and coloured contour but like [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/). Any suggestions without stylesheet?

The following is solved:

Because by searching for the solution I found style sheets, but I get the following error message trying to load specific stylesheets in python matplotlib following the official [manual](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.use('ggplot')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

same problem with:

```
>>> print plt.style.available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Information about the system:

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
```

So it seems that something is wrong with my installation, but what can I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [the release notes](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html), the `style` package was added in matplotlib 1.4.  You will need to upgrade if you want to use that.

Comment: thanks for the advice, so I will wait for a pre-built package containing version 1.4.

Comment: @bijah: What platform are you on?  There are binary downloads on [the matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html).

Comment: @BranBarn: I am on ubuntu 14.4. I started reading through the installation site, but had no real insight, so I thought I will wait...